# Hiding gettext parameter (locale=en) from URL

Tags: php, session, cookies, gettext

I am using PHP's gettext extension to translate my website to different languages. I have three links that change the language based on URL:

```
$locale = false;
if (isSet($_GET["locale"])){
  $locale = $_GET["locale"];
  setcookie("locale", $locale, time()+60*60*24*30, "/");
}
if (!$locale && isSet($_COOKIE["locale"])){
  $locale = $_COOKIE["locale"];
}
putenv("LC_ALL=$locale");
putenv("LANGUAGE=$locale");
setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale);
bindtextdomain("messages", "./locale");
bind_textdomain_codeset("messages", "UTF-8");
textdomain("messages");
```

with
    `<a href="?locale=en">English</a>` and
    `<a href="?locale=ru">Russian</a>`

I wanted to keep the URL clean and have those `?lang=en` parameter out of the URL. So, when user clicks on a lin to `products.php`, it will stay as it is and not show `products.php?locale=ru` How can I do that?

Comment: You could set a cookie, couldn't you? Your code is already prepared for that

Comment: And actually you should neither. There is a header in `$_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"]` for that. Use cookies and language buttons only as fallback, but no more.

Comment: Pekka: I didn't write it, I saw it as an example on some site

Comment: @mario well, if he has a multi-language site and wants the user to pick one regardless of accept-language, he has to do *something*..

Comment: mario: That's good, but that would change the language to whatever language the web browser is right?

Comment: But strike my cookie idea, that is dumb - it'll make it impossible to have different versions of the site open at the same time. No, it'll have to be *somewhere* in the URL if you want the user to be able to freely pick the language.

Comment: No, actually it's OK if it's impossible to have different versions of website open at the same time. Obviously, a user who chose for ex. German wouldn't want to go back to English. I know people here don't like spoon-feeding, but how can I have it in cookie or session as you said?

Comment: @delrt I added a paragraph to my answer. Your code above seems to be already doing that

Answer (score 0):

If you want

- The user to be able to pick the language freely, regardless of browser language
- The user to be able to have different tabs open with different language versions of your site

then there is no way around putting the language information somewhere in the URL. Either using a GET parameter like you do, or by masking it using mod_rewrite into something like

```
www.domain.com/en/pagename.php
```

if you're fine with the tabs problem, then set the language in a cookie. Actually, the code you show above already does that. The `?lang=xx` parameter is necessary only when actually switching the language.

Comment: Using mod_rewrite was my plan B. I was just wondering how to do it the way Twitter and Facebook does, with no parameters in the URL.

Comment: @delrt they most likely use information stored in the database about the user who is currently logged in.